# Best way to lay text over an image halfway

Tags: html, css, sass, materialize

Looking overlay an text over an image halfway. Best practice to achieve this?

[Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLbqV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place your image absolutely at 60% of the left and and your text from 0% of the left to 80% *(for example)* with :

```
.image{
  position:absolute;
  left:60%;
  ...
}
.text{
  width:80%;
  ...
}
```

---

Here is a working snippet:

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

.image{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:60%;
  width:40%;
  height:100%;  
}

.text{
  width:80%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/Gatojpm.jpg/800px-Gatojpm.jpg" alt="Smiley face">  
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum convallis turpis vel tempor. Aliquam vitae ultricies magna. Fusce ex purus, venenatis eu lectus at, pretium semper lectus. Etiam posuere convallis enim, ut scelerisque mi tristique at. Vivamus condimentum, justo id fringilla luctus, massa ante varius leo, non consectetur lectus quam ut ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus tempor blandit libero. Mauris vulputate elit ante, at porta nisi interdum ac. Quisque fringilla ipsum id ex fermentum, id aliquam tellus imperdiet. Fusce feugiat, ex in elementum imperdiet, magna elit convallis magna, a rutrum neque dui id odio. Ut rutrum lectus nec sodales volutpat. Sed eleifend est velit, vitae consequat libero sollicitudin ut. Nulla ac convallis nisi.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class like so and insert your image link inside:
2. Create a class after your image:
3. Insert css

```css
.imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img src="myImage.jpg" alt="myImage" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">This text is in the bottom left</div>
  <div class="top-left">This text is in the top left.</div>
  <div class="top-right">This text is in the top right.</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">This text is in the bottom right.</div>
  <div class="centered">This text is centered.</div>
</div>
```